# Format \label Argument

Tags: labels, arguments

I'd like to automatically format an argument before passing it onto `\label`; I tried messing with expansion & co., but I'm not figuring it out. A quick hint would be much appreciated, thanks!

**MWE** (throws `Missing \endcsname inserted` and `Extra \endcsname` errors):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}\label{\MakeLowercase{Some Text}}

See \ref{some text}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: why don't you simply write directly \label{some text}?

Comment: `\label` should just have simple ascii text it is not used for typesetting at all, it is just an internal identifier, `\MakeLowercase` is a typesetting command.

Comment: It is rarely a good idea to generate a `\label` as you need to know what it is when authoring, to use with `\ref`. so it is better to add them by hand.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The actual usage will be something like `\newcommand{\mycmd}[1]{\section{#1}\label{\MakeLowercase{#1}}}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'd agree, except in this case I find myself almost always using the lowercase of the section title, so it'd be nice if I could automatically generate those labels (and e.g. override it with a custom one if an optional argument is provided, which won't be hard to do)

Comment: you are looking for `\lowercase{\label{#1}}` but I'd really strongly advise not to do that.

Comment: it is a bad idea to use the section title. If you decide to change it from "some text" to "some other text" all your references will fail.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Okay yeah that's perfect, I'm sorry I missed that. Why do you advise against it? Is it just a matter of preference, or is the command unstable?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Fair point, but right now I'm doing that anyways (i.e. changing all my references if I change the section title), since I couldn't stand having the `\label` differ too much from my `\section` title

Comment: well it fails if you put anything in the title not allowed in a `\csname` and it loses much of the point of the `\label` `\ref` mechanism, that the label should be in internal,meaningful ID that allows cross references to keep working even as the document is edited.

Comment: well that is a bit missing the point of a label. But beside this: are you absolutly, completely sure that your section title will never contain anything that \label and \lowercase won't like?

Comment: To @DavidCarlisle 's point...if your section title contains a greek letter or a formatting command of some sort, it won't work in the label.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes greek letters should work (at least with a current latex).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Well, no, I'm never absolutely sure, but that's what the hypothetical optional argument would be for, just like there's an optional argument if you want to change the default ToC entry of a section

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Maybe unicode versions of Greek letters, but not things like `\label{\beta}`, at least in my latex.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes \beta is not a greek letter, but a math command ;-).

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes "unicode versions of Greek letters" is normally written as "Greek Letters" this century:-)

Comment: Semantics, shamantics! @DavidCarlisle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
\newcommand{\mycmd}[1]{\section{#1}\lowercase{\label{#1}}}
```

However this binds the internal label to the typeset section title.

At a technical level it will fail if the section title contains anything that is not allowed in a `\csname` such as math or a line break. It is possible to use more complicated functions than `\lowercase` (eg the expl3 text functions) that would avoid some of those issues, but a more conceptual issue is that this loses the point of `\label` that it should be an author-chosen internal ID that allows stable cross referencing even as the document is edited and sections change order or have headings edited.

Answer (score 1):

Here, `\speclabel{}` will take its argument, strip out all command sequences, spaces, and groups, and make a label of the lowercase version of what remains.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tokcycle}
\newcommand\speclabel[1]{\protect\speclabelaux{#1}}%
\newcommand\speclabelaux[1]{%
  \tokcycle{\addcytoks{##1}}{}{}{}{#1}%
  \expandafter\lowercase\expandafter{\expandafter\label\expandafter{\the\cytoks}}%
}
\begin{document}
\section{My Section\speclabel{My Section}}

\subsection{My $\beta$ Subsection for \today%
 \speclabel{My $\beta$ Subsection for \today}}

In section \ref{mysection} and subsection \ref{my$$subsectionfor}
\end{document}
```

[image]